# How to join two Access tables into one DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I want the user to be able to see what tickets (tblTickets) and orders (tblOrders) in a datagridview (dgvDynamic).

Howver, I recieve in error when clicking "btnDisplay" that states there was an error with the formatting of the FROM statement. I'm unsure of how to actually join the two tables so that when the condition is met, the records would appear in the table.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Public Class frmViewTables
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb"
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim tables As DataTableCollection
        Dim source1 As New BindingSource
        Dim dt As DataTable

        Private Sub btnDisplayDataGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayDataGrid.Click

            Dim source1 As New BindingSource
            Dim ds = New DataSet
            Dim tables = ds.Tables
            Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb")
            Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [tblOrders] inner join [tblTickets] where Username = @username", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = frmLogin.SuccessfulLoginUsername
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")
            Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
            source1.DataSource = view
            dgvDynamic.DataSource = view
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: You're missing the `ON` clause of your inner join. You need to describe how the two tables are joined, or use a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, look up the correct syntax if you are not sure (don't guess?!).

Answer (score 0):

It looks the error is in query syntax. The inner join should specify joining columns from both tables something like this.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [tblOrders] inner join [tblTickets] ON [tblOrders].OrderID=[tblTickets].OrderID where Username = @username", cn)
```

- I assumed that parent table's tblOrders primary key is OrderID and tblTickets has same name column as foreign key. Correct the "`ON [tblOrders].OrderID=[tblTickets].OrderID`" in above query and feedback whether it worked or not. if not, then share both tables columns info.

-Thanks

Comment: Thank for the response!!! I changed [tblOrders].OrderID to [tblOrders].ID, same for [tblTickets] because they share the same name and are the primary key. Problem is I receive an error highlighting "da.Fill(ds, "tblOrders")" stating that: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The specified field 'Username' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.' What I think this means is that because there are two username fields in both the tables it doesn't work. So I guess I will have to create a listbox which shows the two tables in the database and you can then

Comment: Continuation from the previous comment: Select which table in the listbox to display on the DataGridView. I just don't know at all how to do that. Thanks for your help @Munawar appreciate it.

Comment: Re OleDbException. looks 'Username' exists in both tables so prefix the 'Username' like [tblOrders].Username in where clause.

Comment: Re Continuation, see above comment. also it would be better to use column names in the select statement to return the needed columns only in the select result set in stead of using select *